# Back up one column from a backup database?

Tags: join, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-update

What is the correct update statement for RESTORING (Updating) 1 column from a backup database?

We have a primary ID and can use a second column as an additional criteria if needed.

```
UPDATE db1.dbo.table a SET ImportantNumber = (SELECT ImportantNumber FROM db_bak.dbo.table b) 
WHERE a.primaryKey1 = b.primaryKey1
```

So whatever the values for ImportantNumber were in the backup database should be the new ImportantNumber for all records in the current database. This is SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE a 
SET ImportantNumber = b.ImportantNumber
FROM db1.dbo.table a 
INNER JOIN db_bak.dbo.table b ON a.primaryKey1 = b.primaryKey1
WHERE ...
```

Comment: oops sorry that should be a.primaryKey1 = b.primaryKey1 and could be further qualified by another criteria like `AND a.2ndvalue = b.2ndvalue` if needed

Comment: Then you just add other conditions to ON clause. You may of course use WHERE clause too - whatever looks more maintainable.

Comment: this is not working for some reason.. I am not getting an update to the column

Comment: If you just select rows with same condition (SELECT * FROM ...), which records you see? If none, then some of your conditions do not work as expected.